# getting an element inside json object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this json in my server:

```
{"user":"bla","password":"passbla"}
```

and in side my ts file I accessing it like that:

```
this.http.get('http://myserver.com/myjson.json').subscribe(data => {
     alert(data.text()); });
```

I getting the json text in the alert box all OK.
But I need to access a certain element in this json(let's say the "user" element)
but this :

```
alert(data.user);
```

or

```
alert(data.json().user);
```

are all returning undefined if any...
How do I get a certain element value inside a json like this?

Comment: how about alert(data[0].user);

Comment: Instead of `alert` use `console.log(data)` then look at the object structure in your console. That should show you if you access it by property or if it is an array or similar.

Comment: OK krisph your suggestion with a little add of - json() did the trick...: alert(data.json()[0].user   thanks

Comment: can u share your json structure ?

Comment: better way would be to just console the json and open the json and figure the path

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(data.json()[0].user)
```

is the way to access the element...